# Uniqueness of rank of free module over commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Is the statement that free modules over commutative rings must have unique rank, which refers to the cardinality of the basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M\cong R^n$, pick a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$, then $$M\otimes R/\mathfrak m\cong (R/\mathfrak m)^n$$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $R/\mathfrak m$, therefore $$n=\dim_{R/\mathfrak m} M\otimes R/\mathfrak m$$ is an invariant.

Note that:

(1) We assume $R$ has identity (hence has maximal ideals).

(2) The same argument works when $M\cong\oplus_{i\in I} R$ for index set $I$ of arbitrary cardinality, because direct sum and tensor product distribute.

Comment: What if $R$ doesn't contain identity?

Comment: Then it's not necessarily true. For example, the direct sum $R=\oplus_{i\in\mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ with pointwise operations is a ring without $1$, and $R\cong R\oplus R$ as $R$-modules. For furhter study, you can look at @Sammy_Black's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every commutative ring satisfies the Invariant Basis Number (IBN) property. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) provides a sketch of a proof using Krull’s Theorem, gives examples of other classes of rings with the IBN property, as well as an example of a ring without the IBN property (ring of column-finite infinite matrices) $S$, where it can be shown that $S^m \cong S^n$ for all $m, n \in \Bbb{N}$.